# Pagination in angular material

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-material

Is there any grid component in angular material that supports pagination out there?

The only grid directive available on the documentation page is md-grid-list (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridList) but I see no pagination options.

Comment: you need data table?

Comment: I need to display a list of items, not necessarily a table.

Comment: you can do pagination with all the ontrols

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Angular 2.x+ you can use this component as shown here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview